# jquery validation not working

Tags: jquery, validation, cakephp

I have jQuery validation on many forms. The problem is that on some of the form the validation does not work, yet the same code is used. I have spent many hours and cannot see what is wrong with the code. They both get loaded in by ajax.

Here is a form that the validation does not work on:

```
            <div id="form_box">

                <?php echo $this->Form->create('Room');?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('id');?>

                    <div id="form_tabs" class="column span-17">

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#form_tabs-1">Room</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#form_tabs-2">Description</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#form_tabs-3">Rates</a></li>   
                            <li><a href="#form_tabs-4">Attached Images</a></li> 
                        </ul>

                        <div id="form_tabs-1">
                        <?php
                                echo $this->Form->input('title',array('class'=>'form_input'));          

                                echo $this->Form->input('enabled',array('class'=>'form_input'));
                                //echo $this->Form->input('no_of_rooms',array('class'=>'form_input'));
                        ?>

                            <div class="input text"><label for="RoomListNo">Display Order</label>   
                            <?
                                echo $res->getNumDrop(10, null, $this->data['Room']['list_no'], 'RoomListNo','data[Room][list_no]');
                            ?>
                            </div>  

                        <hr />
                        <?php
                                echo $this->Form->input('min_adults',array('class'=>'form_input'));         
                                echo $this->Form->input('max_adults',array('class'=>'form_input'));
                                echo $this->Form->input('max_children',array('class'=>'form_input'));
                        ?>          
                        </div>

                        <div id="form_tabs-2">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->input('description');?>
                        </div>

                        <div id="form_tabs-3">
                                <h3>Related Rates</h3>
                        <?php   
                                //echo $this->Form->input('AddOn',array('class'=>''));
                                echo $this->Form->input('Rate',array('class'=>'multiselect','label'=>false));
                        ?>
                        </div>      


                        <div id="form_tabs-4">

                            <div id="uploader"></div>

                            <div class="boxgrid grid_8">
                            <?php echo $this->element('attachments',array('control'=>'rooms','id'=>$this->data['Room']['id'],'att'=>$this->data['Attachment'])); ?>     
                            </div>

                            <hr />

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <?php echo $this->element('form_col'); ?>

                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="error_msg"></div>

            <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("div#uploader").resloader();
                $("div#uploader").load('<?=BASE_URL?>/admin/rooms/addfiles/<?=$this->data['Room']['id']?>',null,function(){}).fadeIn();


                $(".multiselect").multiselect();

                // validate form on keyup and submit
                $("#RoomEditForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        'data[Room][title]':        {required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength:32 },
                        'data[Rate][Rate][]':       {required: true},
                        'data[Room][max_adults]':   {required: true, digits: true, minlength: 1, maxlength:2 },
                        'data[Room][max_children]': {required: true, digits: true, minlength: 1, maxlength:2 }

                    },
                    messages: {
                        'data[Room][title]':        {required: "Please Enter a Room title"},
                        'data[Rate][Rate][]':       {required: "Please select at least one Rate"},
                        'data[Room][max_adults]':   {required: "Max Adults must be numeric "},
                        'data[Room][max_children]': {required: "Max Children must be numeric "}

                    },
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                            $('#error_msg').html(error);
                    }
                });


            });
            </script>
```

Here is a form that the validation is working correctly:

```
            <div id="form_box">

                <?php echo $this->Form->create('AddOn', array('id'=>'AddOnEditForm','url'=>'/admin/upgrades/edit'));?>
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('id');?>

                    <div id="form_tabs" class="column span-17">

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#form_tabs-1">Add On</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#form_tabs-2">Description</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#form_tabs-3">Dates</a></li>   
                            <li><a href="#form_tabs-4">Related Data</a></li>    
                            <li><a href="#form_tabs-5">Attached Images</a></li>     
                        </ul>

                        <div id="form_tabs-1">
                            <?php
                                echo $this->Form->input('title',array('class'=>'form_input'));          
                                echo $this->Form->input('price',array('class'=>'form_input'));
                            ?>  
                            <div class="input text"><label for="AddOnPriceQuoteAs">Price Quote As</label>   
                            <?php 
                                echo $res->getPriceQuoteDrop($this->data['AddOn']['price_quote_as'],'AddOnPriceQuoteAs','data[AddOn][price_quote_as]'); 
                            ?>              
                            </div>
                            <hr />      
                            <?php
                                echo $this->Form->input('add_on_category_id',array('class'=>'form_input','label'=>'Category'));
                                echo $this->Form->input('enabled',array('class'=>'form_input'));
                            ?>  

                            <div class="input text"><label for="AddOnListNo">Display Order</label>  
                            <?
                                echo $res->getNumDrop(10, null, $this->data['AddOn']['list_no'], 'AddOnListNo','data[AddOn][list_no]');
                            ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="form_tabs-2">
                            <?php echo $this->Form->input('description');?>
                        </div>

                        <div id="form_tabs-3">

                            <div class="input select">
                            <label for="AddOnAvailabilityDrop">Availability</label>
                            <?
                                echo $res->getAvailabilityDrop($this->data['AddOn']['availability'],'AddOnAvailabile','data[AddOn][available][]');
                            ?>
                            </div>          

                            <div class="input text">
                            <label for="AddOnValidFrom">Valid From</label>
                                <input id="AddOnValidFrom" class="form_input form_datepicker" name="data[AddOn][valid_from]" 
                                type="text" value="<?=$this->data['AddOn']['valid_from']?>" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="input text">
                            <label for="AddOnValidTo">Valid To</label>
                                <input id="AddOnValidTo" class="form_input form_datepicker" name="data[AddOn][valid_to]" 
                                type="text" value="<?=$this->data['AddOn']['valid_to']?>" />
                            </div>  

                        </div>

                        <div id="form_tabs-4">
                            <h3>Relates to these Rate+Room combinations:</h3>
                            <?php   
                                foreach($this->data['AddOnRateroom'] as $rr){
                            ?>
                                    <strong>Rate:</strong> <?=$rates[$rr['rate_id']]?> + 
                                    <strong>Room:</strong> <?=$rooms[$rr['room_id']]?> (<a href="<?=BASE_URL?>/admin/upgrades/delraterooms/<?=$this->data['AddOn']['id']?>/rate:<?=$rr['rate_id']?>/room:<?=$rr['room_id']?>">x</a>)<br />
                            <?
                                }

                                if (count($this->data['AddOnRateroom'])==0){ echo 'No Rate+Room Combinations';}
                            ?>

                            <br /><br /><br />

                            <h3>add New Rate+Room Combination</h3>

                            <select id="AddOnRates" name="data[Addon][RR][rate]">
                            <option vlaue="">Choose Rate...</option>
                            <? foreach($rates as $rid=>$rate){ ?>
                                <option value="<?=$rid?>"><?=$rate?></option>
                            <? } ?>
                            </select>
                            <div id="roomloader"></div>

                            <p class="buttons"><a id="gorr" style="display:none" href="<?=BASE_URL?>/admin/upgrades/addraterooms/<?=$this->data['AddOn']['id']?>">GO</a></p>

                        </div>


                        <div id="form_tabs-5">

                            <div id="uploader"></div>
                            <?php echo ($this->data['AddOn']['id']);?>          
                            <div class="boxgrid grid_8">
                            <?php echo $this->element('attachments',array('control'=>'upgrades','id'=>$this->data['AddOn']['id'],'att'=>$this->data['Attachment'])); ?>
                            </div>

                            <hr />

                        </div>  


                    </div>  

                    <?php echo $this->element('form_col'); ?>

                    <? //debug($this->data);?>

                </form>
            </div>

            <div id="error_msg"></div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                    $("div#uploader").resloader();
                    $("div#uploader").load('<?=BASE_URL?>/admin/upgrades/addfiles/<?=$this->data['AddOn']['id']?>',null,function(){}).fadeIn();

                    /* JQuery Datepicker */
                    $('.form_datepicker').datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                    });

                    $('#AddOnRates').change(function(){
                        var rid = $(this).val();
                        var gotohref = '<?=BASE_URL?>/admin/upgrades/getraterooms/'+rid;
                        $("div#roomloader").resloader();
                        $("div#roomloader").load(gotohref,null,function(){}).fadeIn();
                        return false;

                    });

                // validate form on keyup and submit
                $("#AddOnEditForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        'data[AddOn][title]':              {required: true, minlength: 3, maxlength:32 },
                        'data[AddOn][price]':              {required: true, number: true},
                        'data[AddOn][valid_from]':         {required: true, date: true},
                        'data[AddOn][valid_to]':           {required: true, date: true},
                        'data[AddOn][available][]':        {required: true},


                    },
                    messages: {
                        'data[AddOn][title]':            {required: "Please Enter a Rate title"},
                        'data[AddOn][price]':            {required: "Price must be numeric "},
                        'data[AddOn][valid_from]':       {required: "Please enter a valid Date From"},
                        'data[AddOn][valid_to]':         {required: "Please enter a valid Date To  "},
                        'data[AddOn][available][]':      {required: "Please select at least one Availability Day"},

                    },
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                            $('#error_msg').html(error);
                    }
                });

            });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference seems to be the form creation instruction

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Room');?>
```

against

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('AddOn', array('id'=>'AddOnEditForm','url'=>'/admin/upgrades/edit'));?>
```

Seems you're not passing the id for the form that is used by jquery validator. The form creation should be:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Room', array('id'=>'RoomEditForm','url'=>'URLACTIONHERE'));?>
```

Comment: Yep that was it alright, thanks. Because the forms worked I didnt think that it may be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

What's this trailing [] for?  I suspect that might be a problem:

```
'data[Rate][Rate][]':       {required: true},
```